# How do I see values of the stuff I'm trading in adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress-adventure

When I'm trading, I don't see the values of anything I'm carrying, just the weights. Did I miss something at character creation time? What do I need to have to enable values to be displayed?

Answer (score 2):

You can't see the value of your items, however you can just ask for one million dwarfbucks (or another equally exorbitant number), attempt to make the trade and have the shopkeeper make a counter-offer for the actual value of your items or, if you're buying instead of selling, offer to pay 0 dwarfbucks ([more info](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Adventurer_mode#Selling_and_buying_with_money)).

Comment: I didn't see any Appraiser skill at character creation. Did I miss it?

Comment: @orangechicken looks like my memory is playing tricks on me, see updated answer.

Comment: Ah, so I must've run into a bug because I can't ask/offer for currency and the merchant's coins are always tradable items. There's a filed bug related to this: http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=7013

Answer (score 0):

I think you press V in the trade screen in order to see the item value in current versions.

Comment: Is this a guess or do you reason to believe that it's correct? It would be better if you checked if your answer is correct.